# Hopf-manifolds are complete

Tags: riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $M=\mathfrak{R}^2-{0}$ be a manifold equipped with the metric 
\begin{equation}
g=\frac{\langle,\rangle}{x^2+y^2},
\end{equation}
where $\langle,\rangle$ is the standard Euclidean metric. Let furthermore $\Gamma=\langle \mu \rangle$ be the group generated by $\mu:(x,y)\rightarrow (2x,2y)$. Then $\Gamma$ will act properly discontinuously on $(M,g)$. Furthermore the quotient $M/\Gamma$ will be identified with the torus $S^1\times S^1$, which is compact and by standard theorems there exists a covering map $\phi:M\rightarrow M/\Gamma$.

Now on the one hand any geodesic that points towards the origin will not be complete, but on the other hand $M/\Gamma$ is compact and should be complete by Hopf-Rinows theorem.

This seems to be a contradiction. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why $\mu$ is properly discontinuous ?